# Python Diffuse Color

Tags: python, texturing

How do you select diffuse_color in python [image]

Answer (score 1):

Select object then use (for texture sort 0, after create texture):

```
bpy.context.object.active_material.texture_slots[0].use_map_color_diffuse = True
```